# Getting undefined variable error

Tags: php, yii2

```
public function actionSubmit(){
    $event= new Events();
    $address=new Addresses();
    if($event->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $event->save() && $address->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $address->save())
    {
        return $this->render('sucess');
    }
    else{
        return $this->render('unsucess');
    }
}
```

why do get undefined error when i use this $event and $address in the view in form??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function actionSubmit(){
        $event= new Events();
        $address=new Addresses();
        if($event->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $event->save() && $address->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $address->save())
        {
            return $this->render('sucess', ['event' => $event, 'address' => $address]);
        }
        else{
            return $this->render('unsucess', ['event' => $event, 'address' => $address]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why do get undefined error when i use this $event and $address in the
>   view in form??

Because you haven't passed the instance of the model Events & Addresses ( $event and $address) into the views(success & unsuccess). In the controller
you should add the following line of code

```
  return $this->render('sucess',['event'=> $event, 'address' => $ address]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening since the `$event` and `$address` belong to a different model. When the form submit happens for the model Events, `$address` is absent when it happens for the model Address `$event` is absent.

Making the below changes in the if statement would solve the issue,

```
($event->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $event->save()) || ($address->load(yii::$app->request->post()) && $address->save())
```

The logical OR would help the yii to differentiate between corresponding model variables.

My suggestion would be to use different action methods for different models to make it more modular.